# ChromiumEmbedded and WebDriver

Tags: webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, chromium-embedded

Our software uses ChromiumEmbedded that is embedded in a .NET application.  I'm wondering if WebDriver can be used to automate tests for it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that webdriver doesn't yet support Chromium Embedded.  There is an ticket on google code for it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask over at https://sqa.stackexchange.com/ but I've used [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for this kind of thing.  The newer versions of Selenium use WebDriver under the hood: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp